# Creating a bar chart using JSP

Tags: java, jsp, charts, bar-chart

How to create a bar chart through a data from database using jsp.i created two tables in my database (1)cust_entry,(2)cust_response.so plz give me a correct code and which place put your code in my coding.

Thanks in advance.

thanks

```
            <html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Customer Response</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%@page import="java.sql.*" %>
    <%! String Name,date,Desg,Org,Add,Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4,Q5,Q6,Q7,Q8,Q9,Q10,Q11,Q12,Q13,Q14,Q15,Q16;
    Connection con=null;
    Statement Stmt=null;
   // Statement Stmt1=null;
//    ResultSet rs=null;
    String drivername="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String url="jdbc:mysql://106.197.161.194/WiproFeedBack.jsp/wipro";
    String user="root";
    String password ="root";
    %>

            <% 
               Name= request.getParameter("Person");
             date= request.getParameter("Date");
                Desg=request.getParameter("Designation");
             Org=request.getParameter("Organisation");
             Add=request.getParameter("Address");
                 Q1=request.getParameter("group1");
               Q2=request.getParameter("group2");
                   Q3=request.getParameter("group3");
                   Q4=request.getParameter("group4");
                  Q5=request.getParameter("group5");
                     Q6=request.getParameter("group6");
                  Q7=request.getParameter("group7");
                     Q8=request.getParameter("group8");
                    Q9=request.getParameter("group9");
                      Q10=request.getParameter("group10");
                   Q11=request.getParameter("group11");
                     Q12=request.getParameter("group12");
                      Q13=request.getParameter("group13");
                 Q14=request.getParameter("group14");
                  Q15=request.getParameter("group15");
                   Q16=request.getParameter("group16");
                  %>
    <%
    try{
        Class.forName(drivername);
       Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,password);
         Statement Stmt = con.createStatement();
         Stmt.executeUpdate("insert into cust_entry(Name,Date,Desg,Org,Address)  values('"+Name+"','"+date+"','"+Desg+"','"+Org+"','"+Add+"')");

         Stmt.executeUpdate("insert into  cust_response(Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4,Q5,Q6,Q7,Q8,Q9,Q10,Q11,Q12,Q13,Q14,Q15,Q16) values('"+Q1+"','"+Q2+"','"+Q3+"','"+Q4+"','"+Q5+"','"+Q6+"','"+Q7+"','"+Q8+"','"+Q9+"','"+Q10+"','"+Q11+"','"+Q12+"','"+Q13+"','"+Q14+"','"+Q15+"','"+Q16+"')");
    }catch(SQLException  e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    %>

           Name :<%=Name%>
          <br>
           Date:<%=date%>
                 <br>
             Desg:<%=Desg%>
                <br>
             Org:<%=Org%>
                   <br>
               Add:<%=Add%>
                  <br>
               group1:<%=Q1%>
                    <br>
              group2:<%=Q2%>
                   <br>
                group3:<%=Q3%>
                   <br>
                  group4:<%=Q4%>
                  <br>
                  group5:<%=Q5%>
                       <br>
               group6:<%=Q6%>
                  <br>
                  group7:<%=Q7%>
                    <br>
                group8:<%=Q8%>
                     <br>
                 group9:<%=Q9%>
                    <br>
                  group10:<%=Q10%>
                      <br>
                    group11:<%=Q11%>
                       <br>
                       group12:<%=Q12%>
                          <br>
                        group13:<%=Q13%>
                           <br>
                      group14:<%=Q14%>
                            <br>
                       group15:<%=Q15%>
                           <br>
                           group16:<%=Q16%>
              </body>
                 </html>
```

Comment: Actually we can't give you the code since this is not a code dump site. We are here to help you if you face any issue. So the best thing is to show some effort

Comment: ok....sir i m sending you my jsp code.

Comment: thanks for rply me...bt i used in some liabraries bt result is fail.

Comment: There is lot of javascript library available for chart [Extjs, YUI, Mootools], you can opt any of one. You said that u already used library but result fail means you are not using library properly. before apply or direct copy pasting the code it would be better if you can read the library docs and than correlate example code with your requirement.

Comment: yes sir i know many liabraries are available for chart.....bt i directly copy pasting the code.plz give me a code and how to add your code in my code....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a right code to create a pie chart using in jsp.

```
         <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
         <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
              "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

          <%@ page  import="java.awt.*" %>
            <%@ page  import="java.io.*" %>
               <%@ page  import="org.jfree.chart.*" %>
            <%@ page  import="org.jfree.chart.entity.*" %>
             <%@ page  import ="org.jfree.data.general.*"%>
              <%
            final DefaultPieDataset data = new DefaultPieDataset();
             data.setValue("one", new Double(29.26));
             data.setValue("two", (10.0));
            data.setValue("three", new Double(27.5));
               data.setValue("four", new Double(17.5));
             data.setValue("five", new Double(11.0));
             data.setValue("six", new Double(19.4));

              JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart
              ("Pie Chart ", data, true, true, false);

              try {
              final ChartRenderingInfo info = new 
                   ChartRenderingInfo(new StandardEntityCollection());

              final File file1 = new File("C:/FeedBack/piechart.png");
            ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG(
            file1, chart, 600, 400, info);
              } catch (Exception e) {
            out.println(e);
              }
           %>
            <html>
           <head>
             <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" 
             content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
             <title>JSP Page</title>
            </head>
            <body>
             <IMG SRC="piechart.png" WIDTH="600" HEIGHT="400" 
           BORDER="0" USEMAP="#chart">
           </body>
            </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use highcharts library... put your dynamic jsp value in.

```
$(function () {
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'column'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Q_1', 'Q_2', 'Q_3', 'Q_4']
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            cursor: 'pointer',
            point: {
                events: {
                    click: function() {
                        for (var i = 0; i < this.series.data.length; i++) {
                            this.series.data[i].update({ color: '#ECB631' }, true, false);
                        }
                        this.update({ color: '#f00' }, true, false)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [<%=Q_1%>,<%=Q_2%>,<%=Q_3%>,<%=Q_4%>]        
    }]
});
});
```

Comment: thanks for giving me a code.......but sir plz tell me,which place use in this code in my code.....

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/shawson/CkkbF/8/  refer this you will get html example.create jsp page and use your existing code and simply put your bar value in series: [{
        data: [<%=Q_1%>,<%=Q_2%>,<%=Q_3%>,<%=Q_4%>]        
    }]

Comment: abhijeet sir....if u dont mind,plz give me a contact no.i want to talk with you.plz....